# iPhone Grails remoting options

Tags: java, iphone, grails, remoting, rpc

I'm desperately trying to find a suitable solution to connect my iPhone application with my Grails backend. In the past, I have tried HessianKit but it's not maintained anymore. I also tried cocoa-amf but like HessianKit, it doesn't support authentication out of the box.

It seems like the most widespread option is to use RESTful services but I would like to avoid that. Everyone is aware of object-relational impedance mismatch, but for me, object-resource impedance mismatch is at least as annoying. I don't want to serialize my objects into requests and parse responses back into objects. I would like to call remote object methods as if they were local.

What other options are there? What are the most used solutions for Grails/iPhone remoting?

Comment: I have the same requirements as yours and I ended up by implementing RESTful services. Afterwards, I realize that I made a good choice since it was easy to implement and also compatible for any front-end platforms (android, widget...)

Comment: What framework/library did you use on the iPhone side to ease the implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally decided to dig into RestKit and I have to say it's pretty impressive, very powerful and the support on the mailing list is awesome. This really makes REST development easier.